# Another "Skipping acquire..." error

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

I installed [Rodeo](http://rodeo.yhat.com/docs/#installing-rodeo) a few days ago, and now, when I run `sudo apt update`, I get the following line at the end of the list of upgradeable packages:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com rodeo InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I have the following ppa in the source.list file:

```
deb http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com/ rodeo main
# deb-src http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com/ rodeo main
```

I've already looked up similar questions, with the text "Skipping acquire ...", and there are a few ones, but almost all refer to Google Chrome and I don't know how to apply the solutions they give to my specific case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
deb http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com/ rodeo main
# deb-src http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com/ rodeo main
```

to this:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com/ rodeo main
# deb-src [arch=amd64] http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com/ rodeo main
```

Source: https://github.com/yhat/rodeo/issues/615

Comment: @ElderGeek  Actually, I just knew the answer... but adding a source for a similar answer doesn't hurt. Thanks!

Comment: Seeking continuous improvement. Glad to help! :-)

Comment: @heynnema Thank you very much to both (@ElderGeek). It works perfectly!!